# Php conditioning a numeric variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this variable in php $get_user_tipo and it gets their own value from a mysqli field (int) and its a numeric value, i'm usign a number to represent a role, por examble 1 for admins, and 2 for employees.

I want to do a conditional statement for the variable and compare it with a value, for example, (a bad, bad example)

```
if($get_user_tipo=1) {
      do something
} else { 
      Do nothing , just jump to the next check
}
if($get_user_tipo=2) {
      do something
} else { 
      Do nothing , just jump to the next check
}
```

i'm pretty new in PHP

Comment: `if( $get_user_tipo == 1 ) { ... } elseif( $get_user_tipo == 2 ) { ... }  else { ... }` Take a look at [basic php tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you use double equals to compare values.

```
if($get_user_tipo == 1) {
      //do something
} else { 
      //Do nothing , just jump to the next check
}
if($get_user_tipo == 2) {
      //do something
} else { 
      //Do nothing , just jump to the next check
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double = to compare the value as the other answer says

```
<?php

if ($get_user_tipo == 1) {
    //do something
} elseif ($get_user_tipo == 2) {
    //do something
}

?>
```

Comment: Can i do multiple statements with elseif?

Comment: For this example, as the value you are comparing will be the same I am gonna say yes, but if you are gonna compare different variables I suggest to make other if

Comment: @Mr.JonasTheConsultor, yes, but you may want to use a [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) at a certain point.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the other answer, a single `=` is treated as an assignment operator.  This means that you are actually setting `$get_user_tipo` to 1 in the if statement.

What you want is a comparison operator:

- `==` is a loose equals comparison, meaning `'1'` (string) is equal to `1` (integer) (type-juggling).
- `===` is a strict comparison, meaning `'1'` (string) will not be equal to `1` (integer)

The comparison operators manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php